Puzzling redirection with unzip
So I have this command
unzip -t foo.zip '*.bar'

and since there are no files ending in bar I get exit code 11 and the 3 messages lines
Archive:  foo.zip
caution: filename not matched:  *.bar
At least one error was detected in 240729_003641.zip.

That's what I would expect. Now I would like to find out experimentally, which output channel unzip is writing each of these lines. So I first try
unzip -t foo.zip '*.bar' >/dev/null

and get only the caution line. From this I conclude that unzip writes the Archive and the At least one error  lines to stdout,  and the caution line  to stderr.
To double-check I do now a
unzip -t foo.zip '*.bar' 2>/dev/null

and now I get the very same 3 message lines which I see when I did not do any redirection! I would expect to see here only the line saying caution .....
And when I redirect both output channels,
unzip -t foo.zip '*.bar' 2>/dev/null 1>&2

I finally get no output at all. Could someone explain to me this odd behaviour.
BTW, my unzip -v shows:
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.
UPDATE
In case it's relevant:
zsh version 5.8.1
MacOS 12.7.3

Which shell version are you using and on which operating system and version?

@bmike: I ve updated my question with this information, though I don't quite see how tit would be relevant for this problem.

You’d be surprised when people ask windows and other Unix questions here. I also find people are curious to try and reproduce when that detail is provided which gets you eyeballs and answers usually.

I've looked at the source file,unzip is a cross-platform utility which does some rather crazy stuff to work everywhere. At first glance, it should be stdout or stderr, but as you've demonstrated above this is not what actually happens.

@nohillside @user1934428 - that source code is, um, interesting. Did find one spot where it appears to switch between stdout and stderr depending on whether the destination is buffered or not. That might (might!) explain the symptoms seen here.

Interestingly enough, unzip -t foo.zip '*.bar' >1.out 2>2.out sends everything to 1.out. As does unzip -t foo.zip '*.bar' >1.out, but in that case caution: filename not matched:  *.bar is also printed to the terminal (and included in 1.out). So, unzip does check where stdout points to.

@Gairfowl The message is triggered from extract.c, in the section after the Check for unmatched filespecs on command line comment. Info() is defined in unzpriv.h (search for #ifndef Info).

@nohillside : Thanks for doing all this research! I start to wonder, whether this behaviour of unzip should be called a bug, or a feature .....

@user1934428 „unintended feature“ . Need to see whether I find time to get it to compile, and then set some breakpoints.
